# Glitchy graphics in games

Tags: drivers, graphics, games

My question is very similar to this unanswered one: [Every game is glitchy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1265618/every-game-is-glitchy).

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04 and whenever a game is opened, graphical glitches appear at one point or another.
An example is given in this picture:
[Glitch example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fw2Gg.png)

Graphic card is AMD Radeon Vega 3, and the amdgpu driver is in use.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using

Comment: I'm on 18.04, I edited the question